# NSKeyedArchiver with NSMutableArrays and OData Objects causing Memory Leaks

Tags: memory, nsmutablearray, odata, memory-leaks, nskeyedarchiver

I have a memory leak problem using OData where data retrieved from the OData web service is returned in an `NSMutableArray`, i.e. `return [response getResult]`, and then stored using `NSKeyedArchiver` as follows:

```
QueryOperationResponse *response = [dropDownQuery execute];

...

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[response getResult]];
```

When I run the Memory Leak Instrument from Xcode, I am getting a lot of leaks on the NSKeyedArchiver line.

I am thinking that I need to some how make sure that the data retrieved from OData and returned in the `NSMutableArray` complies with the `NSCoding` protocol? The data I am getting back are just strings and integers.

Can I please have some help with this and if anyone has any suggestions on making any objects in `NSMutableArray` comply with `NSCoding`, that would be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fix is to modify the proxy class created from OData as it needs to be modified to comply with the NSCoding protocol.